# How to apply a jq filter to kubectl output in watch mode?

Tags: kubernetes, jq, kubectl

I want to filter the output of a `kubectl` command running in `--watch` mode to keep an eye on changes to a certain k8s annotation. I'm using the following command:

`kubectl get pod my-pod --watch -o json | jq '.metadata.annotations["my-annotation"]'`

Problem is - nothing is printed until I stop the command. I'd like the `jq` to process the input and print it as the changes to `my-pod` happen.

I tried using the `--unbuffered` flag but it doesn't fix it.

Comment: Did you try jq --stream?

Comment: Yes, also tried `jq --stream` flag. Still no results are printed until I kill the command

Answer (score 1):

So i've tested your command and it works perfectly. You are however missing a quote at the end of your command.

```
kubectl get pod nginx-5dfd5597bb-tp8h7 --watch -o json | jq '.metadata.name'
```

gives me

```
"nginx-5dfd5597bb-tp8h7"
```

if you can this command to work but not your own; it is probably related to the brackets and quotes or missing object keys.

Comment: Thanks @Webber, I added the missing quote, it was just a typo in stackoverflow question and doesn't solve the problem. Interesting thing - my colleague, using macOS, also doesn't have this issue. Are you on macOS too?

Comment: i'm on `windows`, using `bash` in `ubuntu` in `Windows subsystem for linux (WSL)`.

Comment: Interesting. I'm on `ubuntu` using `fish shell`. When I switched to `bash` it works fine.